# Line of dots in the \listofalgorithms

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithm2e

I've been working with the ToC, LoF, LoT and more recently with the LoA (List of Algorithms) of my dissertation. I'm using the `tocloft` package so I can set their styles the way I want. My first problem was making these dots closer. I resolved that by renewing some commands and removing the separators from them.

I'm using the `algorithm2e` package to manage my algorithms and get the command `\listofalgorithms`. The index is well generated but the dots are still separated. I've tried to use the `\newlistof` but it didn't work. Also using renewing the command `\renewcommand{\cftalgorithmleader}{~\cftdotfill{}}` but it says that `\cftalgorithmleader` is undefined.

Here we have a minimal example of the problem where the dots are still separated in the list of algorithms.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[portuguese,algosection,algoruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{~\cftdotfill{}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{~\cftdotfill{}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecleader}{~\cftdotfill{}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{~\cftdotfill{}}
\renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{~\cftdotfill{}}
\renewcommand{\cfttableader}{~\cftdotfill{}}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{~\cftdotfill{}}
\renewcommand{\cftparaleader}{~\cftdotfill{}}

% \renewcommand{\cftalgorithmleader}{~\cftdotfill{}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\listofalgorithms

\chapter{One}
\section{OnedotOne}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{this first text}
\caption{first algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\chapter{Two}
\section{TwodotOne}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{this second text}
\caption{second algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`algorithm2e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e) manages its own List of Algorithms (LoA). That's why [`tocloft`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft) has no idea what to do with the command `\cftalgorithmleader`. Moreover, it actually references the algorithms in the LoA as an `algocf`, and not an `algorithm`. Either way, you have to modify the dot separation in the "old fashion way" - by renewal of `\@dotsep`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{0}
\makeatother
\listofalgorithms
```

Here is what it looks like in your MWE:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/inputenc
\usepackage[portuguese,algosection,algoruled,linesnumbered]{algorithm2e}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithm2e
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tocloft
\renewcommand{\cftchapleader}{~\cftdotfill{0}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsecleader}{~\cftdotfill{0}}
\renewcommand{\cftsubsubsecleader}{~\cftdotfill{0}}
\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{~\cftdotfill{0}}
\renewcommand{\cftfigleader}{~\cftdotfill{0}}
\renewcommand{\cfttableader}{~\cftdotfill{0}}
\renewcommand{\cftpartleader}{~\cftdotfill{0}}
\renewcommand{\cftparaleader}{~\cftdotfill{0}}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\@dotsep}{0}% Remove gap between dot leader in LoA.
\makeatother
\listofalgorithms

\chapter{One}
\section{OnedotOne}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{this first text}
\caption{first algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\chapter{Two}
\section{TwodotOne}
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\SetAlgoLined
\KwData{this second text}
\caption{second algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Note that you should *not* specify `\cftdotfill{}`, but rather `\cftdotfill{0}`, since the value that is set (just like with `\@dotsep`) is used as an argument to a unit: `mu`s or `m`ath `u`nits.

Comment: On the spot. Thanks a lot! Do you know if there's how to put some extra space in the beginning of the dots? I want to separate the reference labels from the dots a little more.